# An access violation (segmentation fault) raised in my program

Tags: c++

I'm using Dev C++ as the compiler. When I ran the following program, it said "An access violation (segmentation fault) raised ". I don't know what's wrong with the program. Anyone could help? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Solution {
public:
    string convert(string s, int numRows) {
        int len;
        len = s.length();
        cout<<len<<endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Solution sol;
    string s;
    s = "hi";
    sol.convert(s,3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should give you a warning if you have suitable options turned on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` is a useful set).

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: `I'm using Dev C++ as the compiler`  Dev C++ is *not* a compiler.  It is an IDE.  The compiler that usually comes with Dev C++ is `g++`, and with that, an  outdated version of g++.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a return statement in the function `convert()`.  You either need to make it a void function or return a string from it.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the return statement.